# how do I filter a subform from a combobox that is loctated in another subform in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, subform

I have found a lot of tutorials and questions and answers on how to filter a subform from a parent form, but I am having trouble finding a way to filter a subform with a combobox located in entirely different subform?

```
Private Sub Combo51_AfterUpdate()
      Me.Parent!Address.Form.Filter!Address2.Value = Combo51.Value
End Sub
```

I am getting an object required Error

Address2 is linked to my companyID(control Source) in the Address Form 
Combo51 holds the company Id values

Combo51 is located on the subform CompanyInformation and Address2 is located on the subform Address

The companyinformation form is the child of the parent form Called Quotes. So quotes is my main form with two sub forms CompanyInformation and Address. The Id form the parent form is linked to CompanyInformation; now I want to filter from company information to the Address form by using the companyID from combobox51.

I have success updating text and comboboxes from subform to subform but I just don't quite understand the filter method. Any help would be appreciated.

I am using a query for the record source for the Address form

Comment: Can you give some details of your form design and table structures? You probably need something along the lines of `Me.Parent!Address.Form.Filter = "companyID = " & Combo51`  although it seems from your limited description as though you might not need subforms at all - are you displaying multiple address / CompanyInformation records for a single Company?

Comment: I tried the above code there were no errors but it did not work. I am displaying multiple address per multiple companies. Also have multiple quotes with multiple companies. I need to be able to navigate through all the different address for all the companies along with there quotes. So I will be displaying multiple address/CompanyInformation records for a single company.

Comment: Sorry, still having trouble understanding your data structure. Please provide tables and relationships to make this clearer and allow others to help. When you talk about "multiple addresses per multiple companies" and "multiple quotes for multiple companies" - are these both many-to-many relationships? Can one company have many addresses? Can one address relate to multiple companies? Can one quote relate to multiple companies? Can one company get multiple quotes? I'm guessing that the answers to these questions are not all "yes"!

Comment: I have a tblQuotes Which has a primary key QuoteID which has a one to many relationship with tblCustomerNamesFromQuotes. Then tblCompanyNames has a primary key CustomerNameID and it has a one to many relationship with tblCustomerNamesFromQuotes also. So a customer can have many quotes and a quote can have many customers.

Comment: Next I have two other tables tbl AddressType and tblCustomerAddressesFromQuotes. tblCAFQ  right now has three primary keys first AddressID then CompanyID form tblCompanyNames, and finally AddressTypeID which is from tblAddressType. Table address type has a primary key called AddressTypeId and it references whether or not it is a billing or shipping address or both. I don't not have any relationships established at this time for these tables because I was getting errors in data entry on my form.

Comment: I have one form called Quotes, On this form I have four subforms Contact information, PartInformation, CompanyInformation, and AddressInfomation I want to be able to have multiple companies on one quote with the ability to have multiple address per company. Then I want company contacts to have different numbers and addresses and ONLY ONE part per quote.  I am discovering that access takes alot to explain then what a raw programming language would. I will do my best to get you good descriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am intrigued by your design. I must say that it's unusual to have a many-to-many relationship between Quotes and Companies, but if that's what you need then go with it! [Edit: Just read your latest comments and I can see why you've done this now.] However I am concerned by the "3 primary keys" in tblCAFQ. I am interpreting this as being a "composite primary key" made up of the three columns AddressID, CompanyID and AddressTypeID, in which case I would expect these three IDs to also be foreign keys to other tables. You have identified that CompanyID and AddressTypeID are indeed foreign keys, pointing to tblCompanyNames and tblAddressType respectively, but you haven't said where AddressID points to. I suspect that AddressID is in fact **the** primary key and the other two IDs should just be foreign keys. Anyway, that aside, from the information you have posted so far, I *think* what you need is

```
Private Sub Combo51_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Parent!Address.Form.Filter = "CompanyID = " & Combo51
    Me.Parent!Address.Form.FilterOn = True
    Me.Parent!Address.Form.Requery    'You might not need this, I can't remember if it happens automatically after setting FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

This is assuming that the bound column of Combo51 is picking up the CompanyID (from tblCustomerNamesFromQuotes) on the CompanyInformation subform?

Comment: I still can't get it to work, I AM DONE WITH ACCESS!!! Thanks for your help but It is one road block after another with access. It does some nice things but MAN!! Oh as far as my many to many with quotes and customers not for sure if I am going to use it but the logic is this. We factory that does industial painting. Sometimes we quote a project for a company that is outsourcing a job to us. So company A gets a job to build something from company B. Company A finishes building it and then has us paint it. The quote is for Company A, but it comes in handy to know that in the end it ends up  a B

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I know Access can be a bit 'quirky' at times, but you have to bear in mind that it's a primarily a relational database system (with built in forms and reports designers) and as such you really need to get your data model right to make your forms design easier. A possible way to lose the many-to-many quotes-customers relationship would be to have a tblProject to describe a project and record who the ultimate customer is (B). Each Project can then have many Quotes; against each quote you record who you are directly working for (A). Then a table of QuoteDetails, one per Part.

Comment: I think my biggest problem is my data model I am currently trying to redo it to make more sense, I just jumped into databases head first. I think I will go with tblProject it seems more logical. I have decided to just rebuild my access database and hopefully eliminate the problems with a better design

Answer (score 0):

Try also to turn FilterOn:

```
Private Sub Combo51_AfterUpdate()
      Me.Parent!Address.Form.Filter = "Address2 = '" & Me!Combo51.Value & "'"
      Me.Parent!Address.Form.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the above code but a window as for to enter a value for the filter

Comment: Then you probably don't have a field named Address2.